# Submitting form with HtmlUnit

Tags: javascript, java, html, forms, htmlunit

Is there someone that know how to submit this form with HtmlUnit, Java?

```
    <form name="sendSmsForm" method="POST" action="/talkmore3/servlet/SendSmsFromSelfcare" onsubmit="return checkBeforeSubmit();">
      <input type="hidden" value name="message1" id="message1"/>
      <input type="hidden" value name="list" id="list"/>
     <table border="0" width="560">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div id="ContactListPanel">
                <iframe height="425" width="560" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="ContactListFrame" name="ContactListFrame" src="/talkmore3/servlet/ManageContactList">
                </iframe>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr align="left">
            <td colspan="2" align="left">        
<div class="button_green" style="width: 114px; float: left;margin-left: 130px">
                <a href="javascript:sendSMS();" title="Send SMS">
                  <span>
                    Send SMS
                  </span>
                </a>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </form>
```

I have tried with this:

```
HtmlForm form = page.getFormByName("sendSmsForm");
form.getInputByName("list").setValueAttribute("99999999");
form.getInputByName("message1").setValueAttribute("test");
HtmlAnchor submit = page.getFirstByXPath("//a[@href='javascript:sendSMS();']");
submit.click();
```

But it seems like it does not get the values of the input..

Comment: try to get the form by index number instead of the form name

Answer (score 3):

As you can see, this html contains some js scripts, so you'll need to run it to get the desired behavior.

Try something like:

```
HtmlForm form = page.getFormByName("sendSmsForm");
form.getInputByName("list").setValueAttribute("99999999");
form.getInputByName("message1").setValueAttribute("test");

page = (HtmlPage) page.executeJavaScript("checkBeforeSubmit()").getNewPage(); // from onsubmit
page = (HtmlPage) page.executeJavaScript("sendSMS()").getNewPage(); //from submit link
```

this code should set the form values, validate the form and then do some action with the sendSMS() method.

Usually you need to track the js in these pages. Some of them listen input changes, do some kind of validation, etc. 
Also, take look in the `checkBeforeSubmit` and `sendSMS` functions to see what they are doing with your page.

Comment: thank's for answer. Help please with similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44919818/how-to-submit-file-in-form-with-htmlunit