# How to submit file in form with HtmlUnit

Tags: java, htmlunit

I have a problem with this form

```
<form action="/incoming/Upload.cfg" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onsubmit="return doSubmit();">
  <table id="autoWidth" border="0" style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="h1" colspan="4" id="t_title">
          Резервная копия и Восстановление
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="blue" colspan="4"/>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="Item" id="t_backup">
          Сохранить:
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">
          <input type="button" class="buttonBigL" name="Backup" value="Резервная копия" onclick="location.href='config.bin';"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="Item" id="t_file">
          Файл:
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="text" name="filename" type="file" size="20" onkeydown="return false"/>

            
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="Restore" type="submit" class="buttonBigL" id="Submit" value="Восстановить"/>
        </td>
        <td width="100%">
           
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="blue" colspan="4"/>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

I want to insert "Backup" file and submit form (in browser click to the "Restore button"). Code.

```
private String model = "src/test/resources/config.bin";
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
        webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(20000);
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
  webClient.setConfirmHandler(new ConfirmHandler() {
            public boolean handleConfirm(Page page, String message) {
                System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!1123");
                return true;
            }
        });
 final HtmlPage frame = ((HtmlPage) page.getFrameByName("frame").getEnclosedPage());

        List<HtmlForm> forms = mainFrame.getForms();

        HtmlForm htmlForm = forms.get(0);

        htmlForm.<HtmlFileInput>getInputByName("filename").setValueAttribute(model);
        htmlForm.<HtmlFileInput>getInputByName("filename").setContentType("multipart/form-data");
        HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) mainFrame.executeJavaScript("return doSubmit()").getNewPage();
```

When I execute JS i have Error

> StrictErrorReporter: error: message=[invalid return]
>   sourceName=[injected script] line=[1] lineSource=[return doSubmit()]
>   lineOffset=[7]

When I use

```
htmlForm.getInputByName("Restore").click();
```

nothing happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is working, the overload goes. But I ran the tests in the spring container, and for some reason I got this error.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
```

If you run without springs everything works.

```
htmlForm.<HtmlFileInput>getInputByName("filename").setValueAttribute(model);
htmlForm.<HtmlFileInput>getInputByName("filename").setContentType("multipart/form-data");
HtmlPage restore = htmlForm.getInputByName("Restore").click();
```

**Refresh**

The problem is - "*Target server failed to respond exception.*" 
I avoid this across

```
        webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(20000);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
```

Decided